# Is ECDSA in EOS still viable?

Tags: eosio.cdt

I initially came from Ethereum and found out about ECDSA there. I'd like to do something similar at EOS.

I have found this code: https://github.com/miguelmota/eos-ecverify but it doesn't compile when I run it through the compiler locally, is this outdated or is ECDSA not recommended at EOS anymore due to the multi-sig/cosigning options?

Thanks!

Comment: It would  be very helpful if you gave us  additional information about the output when you compile the contract and the version of the cdt used.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that, I'm using version 1.8.1, the output is on this image.

https://imgur.com/a/uqCuTC6

I have tried solving that error by using 
`#include <eosio/eosio.hpp>`
instead of 
`#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>`

And the error after that is the second image on the link above.

Thank you for your help!